# Calculate beam angel using throw distance and spot size

Tags: python, quadratic-programming

I am trying to figure out the formula on this [link,](https://store.marinebeam.com/beam-angle-calculator-1/)
and create a quadratic calculator that works each way basically. At this point I am only trying to calculate the beam angel using throw distance and spot size using the [Full Width Half Maximum (FWHM) Angle method](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2022/04/04/fwhm-quadratic/#:%7E:text=Full%20width%20half%20maximum,(x0)%20%2F%202). I have a basic python program but my results are never similar to what [this website](https://store.marinebeam.com/beam-angle-calculator-1/) calcualtes.  I know its a long shot but any suggestions would be greatly appriciated:

```
import math
def calculate_beam_angle(throw_distance, spot_size):
    # Calculate the half-maximum angle
    half_max_angle = math.atan(spot_size / throw_distance)

    # Convert the half-maximum angle to degrees
    half_max_angle_degrees = math.degrees(half_max_angle)

    # Calculate the Full Width Half Maximum (FWHM) angle
    fwhm_angle = 2 * half_max_angle_degrees

    return fwhm_angle

# Example usage
throw_dist = float(input("Enter the throw distance (in inches): "))
spot_size = float(input("Enter the spot size (in inches): "))

beam_angle = calculate_beam_angle(throw_dist, spot_size)
print("The beam angle is", beam_angle, "degrees.")
```

e. g. I have 100 for throw distance and 50 for spot size and I should be getting 28.07 for beam angel. but using this program I am getting 53.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers.

Comment: there is no image on this post

Comment: I agree no images but certainly links to code and explanations which are not allowed.

Comment: I dont understand, can ou please point out which sentence exactly is saying that, I am trying to understand what I did wrong with the famous beam angel calculator. I have a sample website and a sample code. what is not allowed?

Comment: You  are using links to expected r5esults and links to the formulae which while they maybe helpful, you should also include a full explanation of what you are trying to accomplish and what results you expect without relying solely on links.

Comment: sorry about that did you see below the code: e. g. I have 100 for throw distance and 50 for spot size and I should be getting 28.07 for beam angel. but using this program I am getting 53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where your script goes wrong, but this is how I would do the calculation

```
import math
def compute_beamAngle(throw_dist: float, spot_sze: float) -> float:
    # Use right triangle characteristics to compute beam angle
    a = math.degrees(math.atan((spot_sze/2)/throw_dist))
    return 2*a
```

`compute_beamAngle(100, 50)` yields 28.072486935852957

I think your error comes about because of the way you attempt to compute half_angle but am not sure.